# Recover table value with 'Window"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 function :

```
function AjoutPanier(Nom)
{

Nombre_ligne_en_caisse = Nombre_ligne_en_caisse + 1 ;

window['Produit_en_caisse_' + Nombre_ligne_en_caisse] = [1, Nom] ;

}



function Encaisser()
{

   for(var i=1; i <= Nombre_ligne_en_caisse; i++)
   {    

   var lol = 'Produit_en_caisse_' + i;
   var Noma = window[lol]  ;

   alert(Noma);

   }

Nombre_ligne_en_caisse = 0;

}
```

If i call AjoutPanier() with the value 'test', the alert(Noma) will show : 1,test

But i only need to show : 'test'.

I have try with :

var lol = 'Produit_en_caisse_' + i + '[2] ;
and all the possibility that i have can but no way !

Do you know how i can get : Produit_en_caisse_1[2] ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Have you tried `alert(Noma[1])` ?

Comment: Yes it's work with Nom[1] ! 
Thanks you very much ;)

Comment: You're welcome :). The reason is in your `AjoutPanier` function you create array of 2 elements, so in function `Encaisser` first element `Nom[0]` would have value of 1 and second element `Nom[1]` would have the 'test'